# GeoServer not returning correct JSON for WFS using OpenLayers.Protocol.Script

Tags: json, openlayers, geoserver

I am trying to get json features from GeoServer 2.3.0.  I have duplicated the code from an example and it works as expected.  However, when I set the url to my GeoServer and desired layer, the returned format isn't the same and results in this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "

The example server returns the json features in this format:

OpenLayers.Protocol.Script.registry.c1({"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"cities.2","geometry": ...

My GeoServer returns the json features in this format:

{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"poi.1","geometry": ...

The error is caused by my GeoServer not returning the json wrapped in the callback function.   This seems to be a server config issue but as a GeoServer noob, I have been unable to find the correct settings to tweak.

Answer (score 3):

Discovered the solution.  The server has JSONP disabled by default.  Setting the environment variable ENABLE_JSONP=true and requesting the format "text/javascript" yields the expected results.   Still not sure why the example server returns the correct jsonp with the requested format of "json".